# make each word clickable in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

ClickableText will return position of clicked character but is it possible to make each word clickable and return it?

```
@Composable
fun SimpleClickableText() {
    ClickableText(
        text = AnnotatedString("Click Me"),
        onClick = { offset ->
            Log.d("ClickableText", "$offset -th character is clicked.")
        }
    )
}
```

for example I have this string -> "This is a sample text" and I want to click word "sample" and return it as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
val text = AnnotatedString("Click Me")
ClickableText(
                text = text,
                onClick = { offset ->
                    val words = text.split(" ")
                    var cursor = 0
                    for (word in words) {
                        cursor += word.length
                        if(offset <= cursor) {
                            Log.d("ClickableText", "$word -th character is clicked.")
                            break
                        }
                        cursor++
                    }
                }
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with an extension function that returns the word index based off a specific character index

```kotlin
fun String.wordByCharIndex(index: Int): Int {
    if (index !in 0..this.length || this.getOrNull(index)?.isWhitespace() ?: false) return ""
    return(this.substring(0, index).count { it == ' ' })
}
```

or its updated version that returns that word directly

```kotlin
fun String.wordByCharIndex(index: Int): String {
    if (index !in 0..this.length || this.getOrNull(index)?.isWhitespace() ?: false) return ""
    return(this.split(" ")[this.substring(0, index).count { it == ' ' }])
}
```

I've tested it against multiple cases, and it works. Not sure if there's a better optimized variant. I was thinking of throwing an `IllegalArgumentExceptoin` if the `index` doesn't fall in the range, but I silently returned an empty string instead.