# How to mix selectable text and clickable text at once?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, jetbrains-compose

I'm trying to build a panel that contains a lot of information. Those informations must be selectable, in order to able the user to copy it. But, beyond this, this information panel contains some parts that, when clicked, must to perform something like a button click (such as navigation, alert, etc).

My problem is that, even properly building an `AnnotatedString` that annotates the clickable parts and setting it to a `ClickableText`, if I put it inside a `SelectionContainer` I can select the text but I can not to click the desired clickable parts (most probably due to multiple clicks handling under the hood).

To illustrate, following have an example of text that should be presented:

```
Date: 99/99/9999
Count: 99999
    
    max: xxxx
    min: xxxx
    mean: xxxx
...
```

The "xxxx" are an example of items that should be clickable.

Then, putting it to a `ClickableText` and, by its time, inside a `SelectionContainer` the text is selectable, but not clickable in the "xxxxx" parts. The `AnnotatedString` was built as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159027/make-each-word-clickable-in-jetpack-compose).

Note that this can be achieved by forgeting the `ClickableText` and building all this information panel using components separately. However I'm wondering how to do this using the existing resources of the API, such as `AnnotatedString`, `ClickableText` and `SelectableContainer`.

Also, if there are another better solution to do that, feel free to show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Build your own tap gesture and consume touch on demand:

   ```
   suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectTapGestureIfMatch(
       onTap: (Offset) -> Boolean,
   ) {
       awaitEachGesture {
           awaitFirstDown()

           val up = waitForUpOrCancellation()
           if (up != null && onTap(up.position)) {
               up.consume()
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66235329/3585796) on how to add tagged annotations to your text and process them when clicked. Then, if you find an annotation, you can do your action and return `true` so it'll be consumed, otherwise return `false` - and `SelectableText` will get that touch.

   ```
   modifier = Modifier
       .pointerInput(Unit) {
           detectTapGestureIfMatch { position ->
               val annotation = layoutResult
                   ?.getOffsetForPosition(position)
                   ?.let { offset ->
                       annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(
                           start = offset,
                           end = offset,
                           tag = "clickableTag",
                       ).firstOrNull()
                   }
               if (annotation != null) {
                   uriHandler.openUri(annotation.item)
                   true
               } else {
                   false
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: The problem was solved as suggested in this answer. Was a bit hard do understand your examples snippets but in the end I got it.If you all are interested in the final implementation I did, it is probably available here(https://github.com/LucasAlfare/FLTimer/blob/view_modeling/ui/src/main/kotlin/com/lucasalfare/fltimer/ui/screens/stats/BasicSelectableAndClickableText.kt#L16) and here(https://github.com/LucasAlfare/FLTimer/blob/view_modeling/ui/src/main/kotlin/com/lucasalfare/fltimer/ui/Misc.kt#L37)